# Set sender name in mail function

Tags: linux, mail-command

How can I set sender name and email address using mail command in shell script.

Comment: By using commandline paramaters (try `mail --help`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
mail -s 'Some Subject' -r 'First Last <you@example.com>' recipient@example.net
```

This sets both `From:` and the envelope sender.

Comment: `mail: invalid option -- 'r'`  :(

Comment: @DanielLoureiro Right, [Heirloom mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) has `-r`, but it isn't required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html).  Still good enough for *BSD and Linux. :)

Comment: works in centos 7 x64

Comment: depends on the mail/mailx implementation in your distro; what I found it works is appending a header variable: `--append="FROM:Foghorn Leghorn <sender@your-domain.com>"`

Comment: @woohoo _depends on the mail/mailx implementation in your distro_ - That of course applies equally to your solution.  With my Heirloom `mailx`: `mail: illegal option -- -`.

Answer (score 21):

The option `-a` populates the header.

**quick command:**

```
mail -a 'From: sender@my-domain.com' recipient@another-domain.fr
```

**long command**

```
mail --append='From: sender@my-domain.com' recipient@another-domain.fr
```

---

> ```
>  Usage: mail [OPTION...] [address...]
>
>   -a, --append=HEADER: VALUE     append given header to 
>                                  the message being sent
>
>   -A, --attach=FILE              attach FILE
>       --content-type=TYPE        set content type for 
>                                  subsequent --attach options
>
>   -e, --exist                    return true if mail exists
>       --encoding=NAME            set encoding for subsequent 
>                                  --attach options
>
>   -E, --exec=COMMAND             execute COMMAND
>
>   -F, --byname                   save messages according to sender
>
>   -H, --headers                  write a header summary and exit
>
>   -i, --ignore                   ignore interrupts
>
>   -n, --norc                     do not read the system mailrc file
>
>   -N, --nosum                    do not display initial header summary
>
>   -p, --print, --read            print all mail to standard output
>
>   -q, --quit                     cause interrupts to terminate program
>
>   -r, --return-address=ADDRESS   use address as the return address 
>                                  when sending mail
>
>   -s, --subject=SUBJ             send a message with the given SUBJECT
>
>   -t, --to                       precede message by a list of addresses
>
>   -u, --user=USER                operate on USER's mailbox
> ```
>
> **Common options**
>
> ```
>   --config-file=FILE, --rcfile=FILE
>                          load this configuration file
>
>   --config-help          show configuration file summary
>
>   --config-lint, --rcfile-lint
>                          check configuration file syntax and exit
>
>   --config-verbose, --rcfile-verbose
>                          verbosely log parsing of the configuration files
>
>   --no-site-config, --no-site-rcfile
>                          do not load site configuration file
>
>   --no-user-config, --no-user-rcfile
>                          do not load user configuration file
>
>   --set=PARAM=VALUE      set configuration parameter
>
>   --show-config-options  show compilation options
> ```
>
> **Global debugging settings**
>
> ```
> --debug-level=LEVEL    set Mailutils debugging level
>
> --debug-line-info      show source info with debugging messages
>
> -?, --help             give this help list
>     --usage            give a short usage message
>
> -V, --version          print program version
> ```
>
> Mandatory or optional arguments to long options are also mandatory or
> optional for any corresponding short options.

Answer (score 6):

That depends which mail client you are using. Some Linux distributions link to `mailx` where you can use the `-r from-addr` parameter.

If you have mutt you should be able to use `mutt -e "set from='name <name@somewhere>'>`.

Other distributions which have the `mail` command should be able to use `echo "test"|mail -s "subject" address@recipient.com -- -f from@address`.